# Close a specific modalDialog in R shiny

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, modal-dialog, showmodaldialog

I have a a scenario in my app that matches the situation in the dummy app below. 
What my real app does is show `checkboxes` in a `dropdownmenu` coming from a `dropdownButton` for every column available in a dataframe for the user to pick from for a model to run on. 
What I am trying to build is a `modalDialog` that is `triggered` on `hover`, that shows a plot of the data in that column on which the user hovers. 
At the moment, I got all of that working, but there is one problem remaining:

If the user closes the `modal` with the `histogram`, the `dialog window` of the dropdownbutton also disappears. How to make only the `plot` `dialog` to `close`, while keeping the one with all the `checkboxes` open?

here is a dummy app with the problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(


  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),

        dropdownButton(label = "CLICK",
                       h5("This is the dropdownbutton window" ),
          checkboxInput("Checker", "Hover for modal dialog"),
          icon = icon("tasks"),
          inputId = "MYDDMbut",
          circle = T, 
          status = "info", 
          tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to open window"), width = "400px")
  ),

    server =  function(input, output, session) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        hist(mtcars$disp)
    })


    onevent('mouseover','Checker',{
      delay(1000, 
            showModal(div(id="ModalDiv", modalDialog(
              inputId = "distPlot",
              title = HTML('<span style="color:#339fff; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Current data column<span>
                           <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ">
                           <span style="color:#339fff; ">x <span>
                           </button> '),
              br(),
              plotOutput("distPlot"),
              br(),
              easyClose = TRUE,
              footer = NULL ))))
      print("2")}, T)
  }
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remove the close cross on the modal & add a OK button on the fotter and put an `observeEvent` on it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(


    ui = fluidPage(
        useShinyjs(),

        dropdownButton(label = "CLICK",
                       h5("This is the dropdownbutton window" ),
                       checkboxInput("Checker", "Hover for modal dialog"),
                       icon = icon("tasks"),
                       inputId = "MYDDMbut",
                       circle = T, 
                       status = "info", 
                       tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to open window"), width = "400px")
    ),

    server =  function(input, output, session) {
        output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
            hist(mtcars$disp)
        })


        onevent('mouseover','Checker',{
                 showModal(div(id="ModalDiv", modalDialog(
                      inputId = "distPlot",
                      title = HTML('<span style="color:#339fff; font-size: 20px; font-weight:bold; font-family:sans-serif ">Current data column<span>'),
                      br(),
                      plotOutput("distPlot"),
                      footer = tagList(actionButton("close", "OK")) )))
            print("2")}, T)

        observeEvent(input$close, {
            removeModal()
            toggleDropdownButton(inputId = "MYDDMbut")
        })
    }
        )
```

Comment: hey thank you qfazille! I was trying the removemodal with an observe as well, didn't manage to find out about the existence of toggleDropdownButton though, which was exactly what I was looking to achieve. Many thanks!

Comment: is there also a way to stop the easyclose of the dropdownButton you know off, and force the user to click a close button in that one too?  There is a situation possible now where the Plot modal is open, and the other one closed because of clicking outside it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your remark. Do you mean that a modal can be close with an other way of the actionButton on the footer ?

Comment: No I mean that the bottom modal coming from the dropdowbutton now closes if you click outside it, or outside the second modal. Which I don't want to happen

Comment: Looks like this is the normal behavior of dropdownButton. I checked on its option but I didn't find a parameters that could allow us to disable this behavior.

Comment: I have spoken with the builder of shinywidgets, he is looking into adding that for me

Comment: another bug in my code is that the delay works the wrong way. It waits to show the modal for a second, rather than only triggering when you hover on 1 spot for 1 second.

Comment: Embarassing.. I think that you could try to make a reproductible example and post it as another question

Comment: for now I will use no delay. Once i have time I will investigate further. Probably need to ask someone like Dean Attali